# Find and return an element from a TreeSet in Java

Tags: java

I have the following Node Class

```
Class Node {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

and then create a TreeSet with the Nodes. Next I wanted to find and return a Node object based on id matching. However, every time the findNode() function is returning the next-to-next Node not the next one. I understand it is because of calling the iterator.next() twice. How can call it only once to check with the id value as well as return the object reference. I also tried with by creating a temporary Object reference but again it was the same result.

```
Class NodeSet {
    Set<Node> set = new TreeSet<Node>();

    public Node findNode(int id) {  
        Iterator<Node> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(iterator.next().getId() == id)               
                return iterator.next();
        }

        return null;                
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Map instead of iterating?

Comment: @JBNizet: could explain a little more with some example kindly?

Comment: Create a `Map<Integer, Node>` containing the IDs as keys, and the corresponding Node as values. When you need a node with a given ID, call `Node theNode = map.get(id)`.

Comment: @JBNizet, what you are suggesting is not related to TreeSet use. Map and Set are two completely different collections.

Comment: @Reddy: don't you think I know that? The OP wants to get nodes by their ID. That's why I suggest using a Map: it's the proper data structure for this usecase.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel and thus let a code less clean and less readable with a huge boilerplate. @JB Nizet is right, prefer using a `Map` for this simple lookup.

Comment: @JBNizet I got your point. Thanks for mentioning this. I was using this TreeSet inside a TreeMap. But I could have been also use another TreeMap inside the parent TreeMap as you said. I needed all the elements to be sorted !! Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283338/getting-an-element-from-a-set

Comment: That said, the "possible duplicate" is technically about Sets, not SortedSets, so the answers may not be as appropriate.

Comment: What's astonishing to me is that there is no "find" or "get" method in TreeSet/SortedSet.  I mean they have every other operation like ceiling, floor, higher, and lower, but not a method for equals to the comparator.  Is there some reason this doesn't exist?  I mean come on man....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Class NodeSet {
    Set<Node> set = new TreeSet<Node>();

    public Node findNode(int id) {  
        Iterator<Node> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Node node = iterator.next();
            if(node.getId() == id)             
                return node;
        }

        return null;                
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already mentioned "I also tried with by creating a temporary Object reference but again it was the same result."

Comment: I would say, check again what you are expecting. This is correct and works pretty well for what you asked. If you are not getting what you want means, it's your design or logical flaw.

Comment: thanks for telling me to check again. There was small bug in the print() function I was using to debug !! The actual code was a bit messy and didn't able to grab the mistake at the first time. thanks again.

Comment: This find algorithm uses a linear search -- the advantage of using a `TreeSet` is that search can be done in logarithmic time! You probably want to use a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 24):

Edit: The solution proposed here is **logarithmic** (unlike the accepted answer) and hence is much faster when the number of nodes in a treeset is large.

There is no *get* method in the *Set* interface which the class *TreeSet* implements. Keeping in mind that there **exists a complete ordering between the elements of a treeset**, a three line hack is as follows:

```
Object search(TreeSet treeset, Object key) {
    Object ceil  = treeset.ceiling(key); // least elt >= key
    Object floor = treeset.floor(key);   // highest elt <= key
    return ceil == floor? ceil : null; 
}
```

Comment: I think that the second `treeset.ceiling(key)` should be replaced by `treeset.floor(key)`

Comment: Yes, I think that would be correct.  I'd also say it would actually be better to just use `floor` and `compareTo`, to save doing two searches.  Apart from that, this is the only answer to suggest a logarithmic time solution, so it gets my vote.

Comment: this is definitely the best answer, with O(log(n)) complexity unlike linear solutions proposed above.

Comment: How can we jump from one Object in TreeSet to the next one in order in O(1)?

Comment: @NathanB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100224/accessing-next-element-in-treeset-in-java

Answer (score 5):

The issue happens here:

```
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            if(iterator.next().getId() == id)               
                return iterator.next();
        }
```

You call twice `iterator.next` in the same loop explaining the "next-to-next" issue.

Make a local variable to still reach the same element or better: use the for loop if you have jdk >= 5:

```
for(Node node: set) {
   if(node.getId() == id) 
     return node;
}
```

As @JB Nizet suggests in his comment above, a simple `Map` already implements your code logic by essence, and thus would better fit than a `TreeSet` and manual check.
More precisely, a `TreeMap`sorted on `Node`s would be relevant. (since it sounds you need the order aspect)

Comment: > I understand it is because of calling the iterator.next() twice

Comment: I've already mentioned
"I also tried with by creating a temporary Object reference but again it was the same result."

Comment: Use the for loop joarder, use the foooorr looop.

Comment: @mopheus  thanks for the suggestions. Actually I was using TreeSet for some other specific purpose. I just show a very simplified code snap here related to this specific question. thanks again.