# Accessing next element in Treeset in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

Is there any way to access the successor or the predecessor of an element in Treeset of Java. Or is there any way of getting the iterator of a particular element so that we can use iterator.next() to get the next element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use higher/lower

with the TreeSet set

is set.higher(e) like e.next() and set.lower(e) like e.prev()

Answer (score 1):

You can get a particular TreeSet's iterator using the iterator() method, and you can retrieve a reverse iterator with the use of descendingIterator() method.