# Mockito - spy of parameterized class calls mock method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, spy, parameterization

I have been scratching my head a lot over something which just happened with Mockito.

I have this class, called `ExamineFilter`, which up to now has not been parameterised.  150+ tests to do with this class and others all passing fine.  Lots of mocking.

I then changed `ExamineFilter` from

```
public class ExamineFilter extends FilteringTokenFilter implements GettableSet<UniqueSequence> {
```

to

```
public class ExamineFilter<V extends UniqueSequenceInterface> extends FilteringTokenFilter implements GettableSet<V> {
```

Now, when I have a spy of `ExamineFilter`, and go

```
spyExamineFilter.add( ... )
```

... this method `add` is ***not called*** but the code carries on. Whereas it was called before.

The `add` method here is in fact from `Set`, because `GettableSet` extends `Set`, and the signature of `Set.add` is

```
public boolean add( V element ){ ...
```

... each time this method is called on the spy it is returning `false`... which seems to be what a mock would do if such a `boolean`-returning method was being mocked.

I've also checked that this is indeed what is going on by finding out what happens if instead of using a spy of `ExamineFilter<...>` I use a real `ExamineFilter<...>`: and, indeed, `add` is called as normal.

Is there a known and documented explanation for this Mockito behaviour? Obviously I'm now trying to think of workarounds to rewrite the handful of tests which have now gone red as a result...

**Addendum**

By the way, for anyone interested, I tried both "flavours" of "callRealMethod":

```
    doCallRealMethod().when( spyExamineFilter ).add( any() ); // results in immediate call (i.e. at this line!) with null argument to add()
    when( spyExamineFilter.add( any())).thenCallRealMethod(); // results in mock "add" call when add() invoked
    when( spyExamineFilter.add( any( UniqueSequence.class ))).thenCallRealMethod(); // results in mock "add" call when add() invoked
    when( spyExamineFilter.add( notNull() )).thenCallRealMethod(); // results in mock "add" call when add() invoked
```

... if any passing Mockito high priests come this way: does any of the above suggest anomalous behaviour which might actually warrant raising an issue with the Mockito team?

Comment: you might wanna add the Annotation `@Override` to see if the method is truly overridding the base method, otherwise your IDE will give you a hint

Comment: can you show us the class definition for `GettableSet`?

Comment: Tx. Yep @Override tag is there all right. I spent an hour trying to find out whether in fact the "target" of add was something other than what I thought! GettableSet is an interface.  You can find out what it's about because it comes from an answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42657502/595305