# Count the average of each list from arrayList of type HashSet

Tags: java, arraylist, average, hashset

I have an `ArrayList` of type `HashSet`

```
ArrayList<HashSet<E>> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

that every key, `array.get(0)` has a list of type `HashSet`

```
array.get(0) = [1895, 1959, 2023, 2087, 1960]

array.get(1) = [2277, 2213, 2278, 2214]
```

now I want to take every list from the arraylist and add them then take the average.

this means for example

```
int sum = 0, avg = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size() ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < array.get(i).size() ; i++){
        sum += array.get(i).get(j);  // this is of course wrong
    }

    avg = sum / array.get(i).size();
    System.out.println("avg of list " + i + "is : " + avg);
}
```

how to do that 
I suggest to hava another arraylist of type integers then add the numbers from `array.get(0)` then count the avg then clear the array and after that add the numbers from `array.get(1)` then count their average and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8+ it can be better :

```
array.stream()
     .mapToDouble(set -> 
         set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average().orElse(0)
     )
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Outputs**

```
1984.8
2245.5
```

---

In your solution you try to get an element from a HashSet with `get(index)` but this is not correct, instead you have to use an Iterator take a look at this QA, [Getting an element from a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283338/getting-an-element-from-a-set), or you can use `for (Integer e : array.get(i))` like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer t : array.get(i)) {
        sum += t;
    }
    double avg = sum / array.get(i).size();
    System.out.println("avg of list " + i + "is : " + avg);
}
```

Note that the sum and avg variable should be reassigned to 0 in each iteration, else you will get wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size() ; i++){
    int sum = 0, avg = 0;
    for(E e : array.get(i)){
        sum += e;
    }
    avg = sum / array.get(i).size();
    System.out.println("avg of list " + i + "is : " + avg); }
}
```

Comment: in sum += e;  , I can't add int with E

Comment: Well, what exactly is E?  It must be some kind of numeric type if you're looking for an average, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use for each loops, to make it clearer?

```
int sum = 0, avg = 0, count = 0;
for (HashSet<Integer> set: array) {
   for (Integer element: set) {
       sum += element;
       count++;
   }
}
avg = sum/count;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly of type E?

If it's of type Integer then it would look like the following:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(Integer e : array.get(i))
        {
            sum += e;
        }
        double avg = sum / array.get(i).size();
        System.out.println("Average of list" + i + "is : " + avg);
    }
```