# Deduplication using a Java Set

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection of objects, let's call them A, B, C, D,... and some are equal to others. If A and C are equal, then I want to replace every reference to C with a reference to A. This means (a) object C can be garbage collected, freeing up memory, and (b) I can later use "==" to compare objects in place of an expensive `equals()` operation. (These objects are large and the `equals()` operation is slow.)

My instinct was to use a `java.util.Set`. When I encounter C I can easily see if there is an entry in the `Set` equal to C. But if there is, there seems to be no easy way to find out what that entry is, and replace my reference to the existing entry. Am I mistaken? Iterating over all the entries to find the one that matches is obviously a non-starter.

Currently, instead of a `Set`, I'm using a `Map` in which the value is always the same as the key. Calling `map.get(C)` then finds A. This works, but it feels incredibly convoluted. Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283338/getting-an-element-from-a-set) and especially its first answer is pretty relevant to this post, although I don't think that it's a duplicate.  From what I can tell though, the Map<T,T> is not an uncommon practice here.

Comment: Looking at the source for `HashSet`, `public boolean add(E e) { return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null; }`. If I'm not mistaken, this is exactly the behaviour you want?

Comment: @NeilEdelman that doesn't return the object it returns true or false.true if there was no mapping and false if the object was already there.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, you want to use `Set` to avoid duplicate objects, but still you override the `.equals()` method `HashMap` or `Set` uses `.equals()` to compare the object, so why don't you use `ArrayList()` but before insert you can check with `contains()` and you can get index by `indexof()`

Comment: You are right. There is not an 'easy' way to get the object. You have to iterate, so maybe your first thought, of using HashSet, is not the best approach

Comment: You also have the SortedSet which enables you to do a binary lookup.But I don't se the MAP as a bad idea. If you don't need order, I would go with the Map.

Comment: How are you defining equivalence?  Is it acceptable to assume transitivity between elements of A and C (i.e. they can be dereferenced interchangably with no side effects)?

Comment: Here is a discussion of what you may be looking for https://www.baeldung.com/java-flyweight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is not simple de-duplication: it is a form of canonicalization.

The standard approach is to use a `Map` rather than a `Set`.  Here's a sketch of how to do it:

```
public <T> List<T> canonicalizeList(List<T> input) {
    HashMap<T, T> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T element: input) {
        T canonical = map.get(element);
        if (canonical == null) {
            element = canonical;
            map.put(canonical, canonical);
        }
        output.add(canonical);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note that this is `O(N)`.  If you can safely assume that the percentage of duplicates in `input` is likely to be small, then you could set the capacity of `map` and `output` to the size of `input`.

---

Now you seem to be saying that you are doing it this way already (last paragraph), and you are asking if there is a better way.  As far as I know, there isn't one.  (The `HashSet` API lets would let you test if a set contains a value equal to `element`, but it does not let you find out what it is in `O(1)`.)

For what it is worth, under the hood the `HashSet<T>` class is implemented as a `HashMap<T, T>`.  So you would not be saving time or space by using a `HashSet` directly ...

Comment: You could probably shorten this to input.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: Yes ... but then the OP might not understand it :-)

Comment: Thanks. This seem to confirm that there isn't a better way than what I'm doing already. Perhaps I should encapsulate my Map<T,T> structure in something that hides the clunkiness in an implementation class rather than exposing it all over the place.