# Fetching and modifying an object in a set in Java

Tags: java, list, set

I have `MyFinalSalad` class consisting of the following elements:

```
AppleClass apple;
BananaClass banana;
PearClass pear;
List<SpicesClass> spices;
```

I have `equals` implemented such as 2 `MyFinalSalad` objects are equal, if they have same `AppleClass`, `BananaClass`, `PearClass` objects in them.

Now, I am creating a `set` of `MyFinalSalad` objects.

And I have the following code:

```
MyFinalSalad mySalad = new MyFinalSalad(apple, banana, pear);
SpiceClass cinnamon = new SpiceClass("cinnamon");
if (mySet.contains(mySalad)) {
    // I want to fetch mySalad object in the set and add cinnamon to the list of spices
} else {
  List<SpiceClass> spices = new ArrayList<>();
  spices.add(cinnamon);
  mySalad.setSpices(spices);
  mySet.add(mySalad);
}
```

To summarize, if `mySalad` is already present in `mySet`, add the `spice` object to the list of `spices` in `mySalad` from `mySet`, else add `mySalad` to `mySet` after creating a new spice `list`, adding `cinnamon` to it and inserting list in `mySalad`.

My question is, if set already has `mySalad` and I want to add a new spice to the list in that object, how do I achieve it?

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7283419/887235 I have the following:

```
mySet.stream().filter(mySalad::equals).findAny().orElse(null).getSpices().add(cinnamon);
```

Is this the only way or the right way to do it? Or is there a better way?

I was thinking that as I am already entering `if` after doing a `contains` check, `orElse(null)` will never be encountered. Thus `null.getSpices()` will never occur. Is this assumption correct?

Is there a better way to do it?

I cannot change `Set` to `Map`.

Comment: As mentioned in the same thread if your thread is NavigableSet you can retrive simply by `Foo bar = set.floor(foo); ` Then do your operation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25393190/1423818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The `orElse(null)` will never take place since you check if the set `contains` the salad right before. You could replace it with `get()`.

However, I would also go one level before and handle it as an Optional, taking the advantage of  `isPresent` and `get` method.

```
Salad mySalad = new Salad();
Optional<Salad> possibleSalad = set.stream().filter(mySalad::equals).findAny();
if (possibleSalad.isPresent()) {
    Salad alreadyExistingSalad = possibleSalad.get();
    // combine spices
} else {
    // add new salad
}
```