# SortedSet.subset returning a size == 0 subset

Tags: java, sorting, set

Go easy on me, this is the first time I've had to work with Comparators on this level.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public T getObjectFromExample(T object)
    {
        if (!sorted)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        SortedSet<T> subset = setReference.subSet(object,object);
        if (subset.size() == 0)
        {
            clsMainProgram.DebugMessage("Returned null for "+object.getClass().getName());
            return null;
        }
        return subset.first();
    }
```

...is a method call I'm using on a TreeSet declared like so.

```
setReference =  Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet<T>(comparator));
```

Here is the comparator

```
public class clsComparator implements Serializable, Comparator<infIDClass> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4212404170394031421L;
    @Override
    public int compare(infIDClass o1, infIDClass o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int z1 = (int)o1.GetID();
                int z2 = (int)o2.GetID();;
                if(z1 > z2)
                    return 1;
                return z2 <= z1 ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

infIDClass is just this:

```
public interface infIDClass {
    public int GetID();
    public int SetID(int newID);
}
```

And the object I am passing to get another object of the same ID is constructed like this:

```
//USED ONLY FOR COMPARISONS
private Building(int bID) {
    this.ID = bID;
}
```

The object that is being passed is simply a blank template with an int ID, and the way that the comparator compares different items into the set is by just sorting the ID integers from lowest to highest. The idea behind this is to get a quick and efficient way of getting an object with an ID from set Reference without having to iterate through the entire thing.

For some reason, whenever I run GetObjectFromExample, it returns a null value half of the time, and when using tailSet and headSet it seems to do the same thing. I'm not entirely sure why it is doing this, the code seems to look right to me.

I have no idea why it would be doing this, apart from some sort of template casting when sending it to the comparator, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: You are probably better off using a Map<Integer,T> for quickly finding values from an integer key.

Comment: You're not calling `SetID` after an object is already in the TreeSet? That will break things, as the Tree won't know that the id has changed.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing @tgdavies, map works better and it's relatively quicker than iterating through it to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your code you have an `SortedSet` (which is just an interface) which is implemented by an `TreeSet` (implementation of the SortedSet interface). I also assume your "dummySearchObject" object/ class used for search for the matching elements within the set "`Building`" is also implementing the `infIDClass` interface - otherwise you would probably already get a compile error.

By specifying the comparator in the TreeSet it is making sure your elements are sorted in the proper order within the TreeSet. In fact the TreeSet is performing all operations based on the `compare(To)` method and therefore on your `Comparator` as described in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

This means breaking the contract of `hashcode` and `equals` method is not the issue here, what I thought is going wrong first (sticking to this contract is very important and if not doing so can lead to unexpected and difficult to find bugs - so you might want to also check for this).

Further from the [JavaDoc of subSet method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet-E-E-):

> ... Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements range from
> fromElement, inclusive, to toElement, exclusive. (**If fromElement and
> toElement are equal, the returned set is empty**.) ...

This means your code is working fine and according to the docs. If you want to retrieve the non empty subset you must specify fromElement and fromElement + 1. This in realty will be hard to do, since we won't know what the fromElement + 1 is going to be. So how can you find/ get the element you're looking for from the Set?

Unfortunately Set implementations don't specify any "get" methods to directly access any element based on their index. So to find your element from the Set you could either

1. Switch to an implementation, which supports such an index access (like HashMap or LinkedHashMap - but your elements won't be sorted anymore. Also remember to satisfy to the `hashcode` and `equals` contract in this case!)
2. You can use an iterator ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283338/getting-an-element-from-a-set)) or stream or the like to find the element by iterating through the Set

*Edit: Remark: Also the implementation of `SortedSet.subSet` will iterate through the whole list to find the matching elements.*

Using the stream can be implemented like this:

```
yourSortedSet.stream().filter((elementFromSet) -> comparator.compare(dummySearchObject, elementFromSet) == 0).findFirst();
```

Note: The stream approach uses the `comparator.compare` method (this is the same Comparator implementation passed into the TreeSet constructor). The comparator implementation is being used, since `hashcode` and `equals` methods are not implemented in your example (at least it's not evident from the above snippet). In case you implement them properly, the equals method can be used to do the "simple" comparison of the objects.

The .findFirst() method will return an instance of an Optional you can proceed to work with. For example (according to your example above):

```
if (!Optional.isPresent())
    {
        clsMainProgram.DebugMessage("Returned null for "+object.getClass().getName());
        return null;
    }
        
return Optional.get();
```

Very important:
The implementation of your Comparator is not wrong or causing the issues, but it is not optimal at all. It will prevent your TreeSet from properly distributing and sorting it's elements letting it become very inefficient.

*Edit: Actually it turned your comparator is implemented correctly, since it's using the full range of -1, 0 and 1 as return values. It is very hard to read/ understand though, so that using the implementation as below is still suggested.*

Therefore using the Comparator implementation like:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(infIDClass::GetID);
```

as suggested by Thomas Kläger in his answer is the way to go. Also your model class is very simple and small if your real-world purpose is more complex you can consider adding another attributes for more efficient storing/ sorting in the TreeSet (only if it also fits your business use case of course. The comparability/ uniqueness of your objects should mainly be driven by your business domain).

Last but not least you can find a complete coded example from the code im referring to below:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Driver {

    static List<Wrapper> dummyData = initializeDummyData();

    // Used to create some dummy data
    private static List<Wrapper> initializeDummyData() {
        List<Wrapper> dummyData = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new MyClass(1), new MyClass(2), new MyClass(3), new MyClass(4), new MyClass(5)));
        return dummyData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator();

        // Creating the SortedSet with a Comparator and filling it with dummy data
        SortedSet<Wrapper> theSortedSet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        theSortedSet.addAll(dummyData);

        Wrapper dummySearchObject = new MyClass(2);
        Wrapper dummySearchObject2 = new MyClass(3);
        
        // Calling subSet and fromElement and toElement are same
        System.out.println(theSortedSet.subSet(dummySearchObject, dummySearchObject));
        // Will print empty result: []
        
        // Calling subSet and toElement is fromElement + 1
        System.out.println(theSortedSet.subSet(dummySearchObject, dummySearchObject2));
        // Will print: [My id is: 2]
        
        
        // Example with stream and Optional
        Optional<Wrapper> retrievedElement = theSortedSet.stream()
                .filter((elementFromSet) -> comparator.compare(dummySearchObject, elementFromSet) == 0).findFirst();

        if(retrievedElement.isPresent()) {
            // Element is there, do something with it
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            // Element is not there
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }

}

interface Wrapper { // Equivalent to infIDClass interface

    public int getId();

}

class MyClass implements Wrapper { // Implementation of infIDClass => Equivalent to Building?
    private int id;

    MyClass(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My id is: " + id;
    }

}

class MyComparator implements Serializable, Comparator<Wrapper> { // The Comparator implementation
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4212404170394031421L;

    @Override
    public int compare(Wrapper o1, Wrapper o2) {

        int z1 = (int) o1.getId();
        int z2 = (int) o2.getId();
        if (z1 > z2)
            return 1;
        return z2 <= z1 ? 0 : -1; // => This should be adjusted (e.g. "Comparator.comparingInt(infIDClass::GetID);") to have an efficient storing/ sorting in the TreeSet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here `SortedSet<T> subset = setReference.subSet(object,object);`

according to [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet(E,%20E))  `subSet` provides you elements between first parameter (inclusively) to second parameter (exclusively). so this call `setReference.subSet(object,object)` will always return empty set